# Can my router code be improved?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a nice url structure for my site.

In my .htaccess I have:

```
FallBackResource /index.php
```

And in my router class I have:

```
class init {

function __construct($url)
{
    $URLElements = explode('/', $url) ; // Adjust if needed.

    if($url)
    {
        $class = $URLElements[0] ;

        if(substr_count($url, '/') == 1)
        {
            $method = $URLElements[1] ;
        }

    }

    if(($t = substr_count($url, '/')) > 1)
    {
        for($i=2;$i<$t+1;$i++) {
            echo $URLElements[$i].'<br />';
        }
    }

}

}
```

Is this ok and what are your thoughts (how can it be improved etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really much to review here, but a few quick items:

- This is going to sound weird at first glance, but you have a route() method that takes a path instead of depending directly on the request uri.

  - A router's job is to route.  By hard coding the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you've made it limited to one data source.
  - `route($path)` would be much more flexible, and it would mean that one object could be used for routing more than 1 time.
  - Think about test driven design.  How would you test a hard coded `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?  (Other than putting a hacky assignment to it somewhere)
- Never assume that array indexes exist

  - If someone goes to `index.php` or `/foo`, so on, then `$URLElements` might not have 2 elements
- As it is, your class does nothing useful -- you probably know that though :)

  - A major improvement would be making it actually do something :)

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your comments (see edit). Yes it doesn't really do anything yet, I will be putting in all the stuff like class_exists and validation etc shortly.